# How to redirect domain from www.example.it to www.example.eu?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, migration

Our company need to migrate domain from:
`www.example.it` -> `www.example.eu`

The `example.it` have some links with 301 redirects like:

`example.it/index.php?id=10&link=slug` (301 redirect to) -> `example.it/c10/slug`

and one more redirect:

`example.it/10/static-keyword/slug` (301 redirect to) -> `example.it/c10/slug`

Now we want to migrate the site. **How should I redirect the website?**

1) Leave old redirect in `example.it` and than only original links redirect to `example.eu`. In example:

`example.it/index.php?id=10&link=slug` (301 redirect to) -> `example.it/c10/slug` (301 redirect to) -> `example.eu/c10/slug`

`example.it/10/static-keyword/slug` (301 redirect to) -> `example.it/c10/slug`  (301 redirect to) -> `example.eu/c10/slug`

2) All links redirect to `example.eu` and then do all other redirects. In example:

`example.it/index.php?id=10&link=slug` (301 redirect to) -> `example.eu/index.php?id=10&link=slug` (301 redirect to) -> `example.eu/c10/slug`

`example.it/10/static-keyword/slug` (301 redirect to) -> `example.eu/10/static-keyword/slug` (301 redirect to) -> `example.eu/c10/slug`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, try to use only one 301 redirection. 301 redirects transfer SEO juice, but you lose a part of it for every one of them (around 10-15%).

You should make a rule to redirect specific cases first, like:
example.it/index.php?id=10&link=slug (301 redirect to) -> example.eu/c10/slug...

Then, if none of these rules are triggered, you should apply example.it -> example.eu redirection.

That way, all your specific pages will redirect immediately to a proper URL and the rest of them will redirect to the same URL on a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

In an *.htaccess* file you could specify the following:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.eu/$1 [R=301,L]
```